# Call the single template from functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call the single template from this function but I'm getting no response. Where have I gone wrong?

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $args = array(
        'p' => $_POST['post_id'],
        'post_type' => 'projects'
        );

    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_single_template() ?>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_die();
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' ); // when the user is logged in
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' ); // when the user is not logged in
```

Edit: I wanted to upload this to show that this works. However, the code above doesn't work. I'm basically trying to replace all the code in the function with a call to the single template which will have the same code in it.

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxURL,
    context: this,
    data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#project-container').html(response);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Previous function**

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $args = array(
        'p' => $_POST['post_id'],
        'post_type' => 'projects'
        );

    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post-container">
        <div id="project-left-content">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <!-- If there is a URL -->
            <?php if( get_field('url') ): ?>
                <div id="icon-full-wrap">
                    <div id="icon-link-wrap">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon-link" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M85.868 85.869c1.599-1.6 3.732-2.48 6.005-2.48c2.273 0 4.4 0.9 6 2.48l16.253 16.3 c0.563 0.6 1.3 0.9 2.1 0.879s1.559-0.316 2.121-0.879l16.253-16.253c0.563-0.562 0.879-1.326 0.879-2.121 s-0.316-1.559-0.879-2.121l-16.253-16.253c-7.081-7.079-16.493-10.977-26.501-10.977c-10.008 0-19.42 3.898-26.501 11 l-48.761 48.761c-7.081 7.081-10.981 16.494-10.981 26.505c0 10 3.9 19.4 11 26.498l16.252 16.3 c7.075 7.1 16.5 11 26.5 10.981c10.011 0 19.424-3.9 26.506-10.981l27.478-27.478c0.884-0.884 1.127-2.223 0.611-3.361 c-0.489-1.077-1.561-1.76-2.731-1.76c-0.067 0-0.133 0.002-0.201 0.007c-0.967 0.065-1.947 0.097-2.914 0.1 c-7.632 0-15.138-2.029-21.705-5.868c-0.472-0.276-0.994-0.41-1.513-0.41c-0.776 0-1.544 0.301-2.122 0.879l-17.398 17.4 c-1.602 1.602-3.734 2.485-6.004 2.485c-2.271 0-4.405-0.882-6.007-2.485l-16.253-16.253c-1.604-1.6-2.487-3.729-2.489-5.996 c-0.001-2.272 0.882-4.408 2.489-6.015L85.868 85.869z"/>
                                <path d="M183.388 32.86l-16.253-16.253C160.059 9.5 150.6 5.6 140.6 5.63c-10.011 0-19.424 3.898-26.505 11 l-27.479 27.49c-0.884 0.884-1.127 2.224-0.61 3.362c0.489 1.1 1.6 1.8 2.7 1.759c0.067 0 0.135-0.002 0.203-0.007 c0.976-0.066 1.965-0.099 2.941-0.099c7.647 0 15.1 2 21.7 5.865c0.474 0.3 1 0.4 1.5 0.4 c0.776 0 1.544-0.301 2.122-0.879l17.41-17.41c1.599-1.6 3.732-2.48 6.005-2.48s4.406 0.9 6 2.48l16.253 16.3 c3.308 3.3 3.3 8.704-0.001 12.018l-48.759 48.759c-1.599 1.603-3.728 2.485-5.996 2.485c-2.273 0-4.41-0.883-6.018-2.487 L85.868 97.879c-0.563-0.562-1.326-0.879-2.121-0.879s-1.559 0.316-2.121 0.879l-16.253 16.253c-1.172 1.172-1.172 3.1 0 4.2 l16.253 16.253c7.081 7.1 16.5 11 26.5 10.981c10.008 0 19.42-3.9 26.501-10.981l48.76-48.76 c7.081-7.078 10.981-16.491 10.981-26.504C194.369 49.4 190.5 39.9 183.4 32.86z"/>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <a href="http://<?php the_field('url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('url'); ?></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="project-right-content">

            <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>

                <div id="slider">

                    <!-- Slider Setup -->
                    <?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
                        $slideNumber = 0;
                        while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();
                        $slideNumber++;
                    ?>

                        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">

                    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>

                    <!-- Slide -->
                    <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>
                        <div id="slides">
                            <div id="overflow">
                                <div class="inner">

                                    <?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
                                    while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();

                                        $slideImage = get_sub_field('slide_image');
                                    ?>

                                    <article>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                    </article>

                                    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>

                                </div><!-- #inner -->
                            </div><!-- #overflow -->
                        </div><!-- #slides -->

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
                        $slideNumber = 0;
                    ?>
                        <div id="active">

                            <?php while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();
                                $slideNumber++;
                            ?>
                                <label for="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>"></label>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                        </div><!-- #active -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!-- #slider -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #project-right-content -->
    </div><!-- .post-container -->

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ajax call was not getting things right you should at least get a '0' as the response. Not even that? Any errors the console?

Having said that, the issues I see start with the line `data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id }`. action will call a function called `load-content`, but that will not do as you cannot have a minus in a function name.
On top of that you have a minus in your php function names in 'add_action'.

I believe in the end the following might work :

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $args = array(
        'p' => $_POST['post_id'],
        'post_type' => 'projects'
        );

    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_single_template() ?>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_die();
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' ); // when the user is logged in
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' ); // when the user is not logged in
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxURL,
    context: this,
    data: {'action': 'my_load_ajax_content', post_id: post_id },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#project-container').html(response);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Add `define('WP_DEBUG',true)` at the beginning of functions.php to help find php errors, and monitor the console for errors. Add `console.log(whatever)` to check if the jquery is running.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Basically, I have a function that is currently working (I uploaded it to the post above) but I'm trying to move that code into the `single.php` template instead and call it instead.

Comment: Hmm, ok. In your theme folder create a file called 'projects-single.php', then add your code to that. Wordpress will look for this file automatically whenever your post has the type of 'projects'. Refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types for displaying custom post types. Hope this helps a tad.

Comment: That's the part I'm stuck on, though. In the first code block above, calling `<?php get_single_template() ?>` doesn't do anything. There is no output. I feel like this isn't an issue with calling a different single template (i.e. `project-single.php`). Shouldn't it still work with the `single.php` call?

Comment: Ok, I a get it. Let me post some code as an example. Will have to be a new answer... just gimme a sec

Comment: Lol. Plan B. get_single_template simply returns the path to the single template. so change it to `echo get_single_template()` and you will see the path name. I think you must just change that to the_content(), and the single.php will be called anyway.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/force-single-page-template-using-a-reserved-term-as-url-parameter might help you a bit as well if you are trying to force using single.php.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown which is used for wordpress ajax request. That's mean you should write those functions in functions.php. Then you should write some javascript code in page.php/single.php whatever you like to get the ajax returns and update the DOM.

You can search wordpress ajax tutorial in google and check this simple [tutorial](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/).

Comment: The function is already in my `functions` file. Also, I do have an Ajax call and I updated my post with it. I'm just curious how I can get the single template from the function.